# Changing name of uploaded file in php

Tags: php, file-upload

I am using the code bellow to upload a file using php and inserting file name into database. Actually I want to rename of file on uploading and want to insert new renamed name into database. I know how to insert name into database but I don't know how to rename uploaded file name. Please help.
I am using code bellow:

```
$target = "uploads/"; 
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']); 

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target);
$add_file = $_FILES['uploaded']['name'];
```

Thank you so much..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
<?php
    rename("/tmp/uploaded_file.txt", "/home/user/login/uploaded/67A7466B576.txt");
?>
```

So new code will be:

```
$target = "uploads/"; 
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']); 
rename($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target);
$add_file_to_db = $target;
```

Comment: I want to insert renamed name into database so what variable I will use to insert into database ? $add_file_to_db  ?

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful for you:

```
$uploaded_file = time()."__".$_FILES['uploaded']['name'];
```

This simply adds time before the name of the file.

Example:

If I uploaded the `AnalysisReport.doc` file, then it simply becomes like `1354173106__AnalysisReport.doc`